# flex-direction is not working as expected in chrome

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, flexbox

Please, guys i need your help flex-direction is not working for me.i have used both chrome and Microsoft edge to rendered it they both displayed the same thing.pls help i have been on this for like two days.I am currently follow tutorial on how to develop responsive web design on youtube.had it been i copied the original source code from the tutorial it displays very well.but if i am coding along as i am watching the tutorial the flex direction is not working at all. htm codes:

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Blogger</title>
     <!--
         -FontAwesome Icons-->
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/all.css">
    <!--Custom Style-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/Style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <!---------------------Navigation------------------------>
    <nav class="nav">
        <div class="nav-menu flex-row">
            <div class="nav-brand">
                <a href="#" class="text-gray">
                  Blooger
                </a>
                <div>
                    <div class="toggle-collapse">
                        <div class="toggle-icons">
                            <i class="fas-fa-bars"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <ul class="nav-items">
                        <li class="nav-link">
                            <a href="#">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-link">
                            <a href="#">Category</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-link">
                            <a href="#">Archive</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-link">
                            <a href="#">Pages</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-link">
                            <a href="#">Contact-Us</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="social text-gray">
                    <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
    </nav>
  <!-------x--------------Navigation----------x----------->


    <!--Custom javaScript-->
  <script ></script>  
</body>

</html>

css codes



@import url('../css/fonts.css');

html, body{
margin:0%;
box-sizing: border-box;
overflow-x: hidden;
}

/*Theme Colors*/
:root{

    --text-gray:#3f4954;
    --text-light:#686666da;
    --bg-color:#0f0f0f;
    --white:#ffffff;
    --midnight:#104f55;

    /* Linear Gradient Colors*/
    --sky:linear-gradient(120deg, #a1c4fd 0%, #c2e9fb 100%);
}
:root{
   /* Theme Font Family */
    --Abel:'Abel', cursive;
    --Anton:'Anton', cursive;
    --Josefin:'Josefin', cursive;
    --Lexend:'Lexend', cursive;
    --Livvic:'Livvic', cursive;
}

/*----------------Global Classes---------------*/
a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: var(--text-gray);
}

.flex-row{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;    
    flex-wrap: wrap;



}

ul{

    list-style-type: none;

}

/*-------x---------Global Classes--------x-------*/

/*---------------navbar-----------------------------*/

.nav{
    background: white;
    padding: 0.2rem;
     height: 0rem;
     min-height:10vh;
     overflow:hidden;
}
.nav.nav-menu{
    justify-content:space-between;


}
.nav.nav-menu>div:last-child{
    margin:auto;
}

.nav.nav-menu::before,
.nav.nav-menu::after {
  content: '';
}

.nav .nav-items{
    display: flex;
    margin:0;
}
.nav .nav-items .nav-link{

    padding: 1.6rem 1rem ;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    position: relative;
    font-family: var(--Abel);
    font-size: 1.6rem;
}


.nav .nav-items .nav-link:hover{
background-color: var(--midnight);

    }
    .nav .nav-items .nav-link:hover a{
        color: var(--white);
    }

.nav.nav-brand a{

    font-size: 1.6rem;
    padding: 1rem 0;
    display: block;
    font-family:var(--Lexend);
    font-size: 1.1rem;

}


.nav .social{
    padding: 1.4rem 0;
}
.nav .social i{

    padding: 0.2rem;
}

.nav .social i:hover{
color: #a1c4cf;
}

/*---x------------navbar---------x--------*/


/*----------------view-port less than or equal to 750px------------------*/
@media only screen and(max-width:750px){
    .nav .nav-menu, .nav .nav-items{
        flex-direction:column;
    }
}
/*------x----------view-port less than or equal to 750px------x------------*/
```

Comment: Have you tried on FireFox. Also I can not see a working sample here

Comment: I don't understand, what you're trying to achieve. Here you have given flex styling to nav-menu which has only child and hence rendering elements as it is.

Comment: If you are trying to achieve nav brand and list in a single row, keep the elements adjacent to each other. Waiting for your clarification.

Comment: @abhijitpadhy i want everything to display in a row.Actually the last child i put is a mistake.i was just rying to test various whether it could work.in the original; code the last:child thing is not there.Actually the code is working if i copy the source code for the tutorial but if i am coding along as i am watching the video tutorial i would not get the actual result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well your content is hidden because of this:

```
.nav{
   background: white;
   padding: 0.2rem;
   height: 0rem;
   min-height:10vh;
   overflow:hidden;
}
```

You set `height` for your nav-bar to `0rem`. And it shows at least a half of block only because of `min-height: 10vh;`

And flex-direction doesn't work because you missed a space here

```
@media only screen and(max-width:750px){
```

And should be

```
@media only screen and (max-width:750px){
```

Comment: it has display flex

Comment: the thing is displaying a little bit as expected when view on a smaller port but the flex direction is not working at all. i do not know the reason why since i have been developing a laravel project with framework.the thingh has started happen in which normal css is not displaying very well on my laptop except css framework.and i want to know how to develop responsive css from scratch by myself pls, help

Comment: @mt4real I just copied your code, corrected those 2 mistakes I mentioned above (0rem height and added space after 'and' in media query) and everything works totally well. You can check it in my codepen. https://codepen.io/roman-boyko/pen/ZEYJGVM

Comment: @mt4real you did everything well with responsive css. You just have to add a space after 'add' in this line `@media only screen and (max-width:750px)`. Because media queries is quite sensitive to that kind of mistakes.

Comment: thanks @boikevich i have seen it i even edited the tutorial original codes in it seems something wrong somewhere.but what actually amazed me is that the complete tutorial codes is working on my system but when i am coding along by watching the video is not functioning may be it is my pc problem lol.Thanks once again i really appreciate your gesture